# How to get checkbox values in android studio with onCheckboxClicked

Tags: android, checkbox, android-volley

private CheckBox ch;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    ch = findViewById(R.id.checkboxCh);

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);

            try{
                jsonObject.put("ch", ch);
            }catch (JSONException exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You have registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            //add request to the requestQueue
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    });

}

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view){
    //Is the view now checked?
    Boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    //Check if checkbox is selected or not
    if(ch.isChecked()){
        //checked=true;
    }else{
        //checked=false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to send the true or false answer from boolean onCheckBoxClicked using JSONObject to my database. But whatever code I tried in if statement was wrong. Do you have any suggestions? I would apreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer in case anyone else has the same problem...

```
private CheckBox ch;

private Boolean checked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
ch = findViewById(R.id.checkboxCh);

register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);

        try{
            jsonObject.put("ch", checked);
        }catch (JSONException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println(response);
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You have registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //add request to the requestQueue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
});

}

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view){
    //Is the view now checked?
    checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

//Check if checkbox is selected or not
if(ch.isChecked()){
    checked=true;
}else{
    checked=false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add new variable like `boolean result = false;`, after that add in

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view){
//Is the view now checked?
Boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

//Check if checkbox is selected or not
if(view.getId() == ch){
   result = checked;
}
```

}

and that in line `jsonObject.put("ch", ch);` change to `jsonObject.put("ch", result);`

i hope this can solve your problem, thanks

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately it gives me again an error in if statement

Comment: maybe you can try to change statement like view.getId() == R.id.checkboxCh. or the variable take it to globe scope and add result = false; in onCreate

Comment: well now it doesn't give me an error in if statement....but maybe i don't post the Boolean data with the correct way in try catch...maybe jsonObject.put() is wrong